# Beantworten von off-topic Fragen

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Oft werden Fragen gestellt, die nach dem Unterschied von X und Y fragen ohne klarzustellen, warum ein Wörterbuch nicht geholfen hat. Diese Fragen werden auch häufig geschlossen, oft aber nicht schnell genug. Meiner Meinung nach sollten wir davon absehen, um die Qualität dieser Seite anzuheben und die Frequenz von solchen Fragen hoffentlich zu senken. Ich fühle mich mittlerweile dazu hingerissen ein -1 auf solche Antworten zu geben, habe bislang aber davon abgesehen.

Wie gehen wir damit um?

Edit:
Wenn in einem Kommentar unter der Frage schon nach Eigeninitiative und -Recherche gefragt wird, sollten Antwortende meiner Meinung nach erstmal abwarten, ob am Eingangspost noch was verändert wird. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob jeder sehen kann, ob eine Frage Closevotes bekommt.

Comment: Der Grund, warum jemand eine solche "Wörterbuchfrage" dennoch beantwortet ist doch, dass sie oder er sie eben nicht für eine Wörterbuchfrage hält. Es stehen mehrere Meinungen gegeneinander.

Comment: Danke, dass Du das  ansprichst! Mir ist das in letzter Zeit auch öfter negativ aufgefallen. Vor allem bei einigen hochdotierten Usern, die die hiesigen Regeln gut kennen sollten, frage ich mich mittlerweile, ob die Regeln bewusst ignoriert werden, weil das eigene Punktekonto wichtiger ist :/

Comment: Ich kann ja mal ein paar Wochen lang das Upvoten einstellen.

Comment: Ob mein am Handy geschriebener Satz richtig ist oder nicht, sollte der Relevanz des Themas egal sein

Comment: Woran messen wir die Qualität der Seite? Es gibt Statistiken für "lebensfähig", die bis ehedem grob bei "3 Antworten / Frage" und "10 Fragen / Tag" und sowas wie "aktiv moderierende Community" - aber was zählt als "gut"? Englisch wurde halt mal aufgespalten in die Paragrafenreiter und die Erklärbären. Deutsch erscheint mir dafür zu klein. (ich kenne ELL zu wenig, um zu wissen, wie rigide translation requests abgebügelt werden)

Comment: @c.p.: Reden wir jetzt über Form oder Inhalt? Ich gehe immer von Inhalt aus. Daher finde ich die weiteren Hinweise unangebracht.

Comment: Qualität kann man zum Beispiel an der Güte der Fragen messen. Off-topic Fragen sind unerwünscht und daher stelle ich mal die waghalsige Behauptung auf, dass diese die Qualität senken. Ähnlich wie zum Beispiel Hausaufgaben Fragen in Math/PhysicsSE, die ohne jegliche  Eigeninitiative und konkretes Unverständnis gepostet werden.

Comment: Könnten wir vielleicht vom persönlichen Geplänkel wieder zurück zur Sache kommen? Statt der Debatte über Tippfehler würde ich mir z.B. lieber Erläuterungen zu den Close-Votes wünschen. Und den Kommentar von @Janka verstehe ich in diesem Zusammenhang leider gar nicht. Da fände ich eine Erläuterung auch hilfreich.

Comment: PS: @ Janka Ich meinte Deinen zweiten Kommentar: *"Ich kann ja mal ein paar Wochen lang das Upvoten einstellen"*

Comment: @Arsak: Wie kann man einen so kurzen Satz, der eine direkte Antwort auf den eigenen Kommentar ist, nicht verstehen? Das ist nun wieder mir rätselhaft. Du schriebst, du »fragst dich mittlerweile, ob die Regeln bewusst ignoriert werden, weil das eigene Punktekonto wichtiger ist.« Ich habe daraufhin geantwortet, dass ich das Upvoten ja mal einige Wochen lang einstellen kann. Vielleicht hast du recht. Vielleicht ziehen diese dummen Benutzer dann ja Leine und wir heben die Qualität der Seite mit einfachen Mitteln erheblich. Man müsste das einfach mal ausprobieren.

Comment: Wir sollten uns im Klaren sein, dass es Nutzer gibt, die es auf eigene Faust nicht schaffen, die Antwort zu finden, obwohl man dafür nur 2 Clicks braucht. Wir können aber nie richtig einschätzen, ob die eigene Recherche unerfolgreich (oder gar nicht stattfand) war mangels Deutschkenntnisse oder eher Motivation. 

Dann gibt es auch die Frage, inwieweit die Regeln Sinn ergeben.

Comment: Die Worte _schuldig_ und _den ersten Stein werfen_ beinhalten bereits eine starke Wertung. Da die Frage sich ja gerade darum dreht, wie wir das Phänomen bewerten wollen, wäre es in meinen Augen besser, diese Wertung in der Frage zu vermeiden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ein Downvote auf eine Antwort, nur weil die Frage an sich unerwünscht ist, halte ich für das falsche Mittel. Der unbedarfte Besucher könnte die Seite trotzdem finden, weil er sich die gleiche Frage gestellt hat, und die Antworte wegen einer negativen Bewertung für falsch halten, obwohl sie richtig ist. Ich finde, dass Downvotes nur für falsche, fehlleitende oder arg zweifelhafte Antworten vergeben werden sollten.

Ich persönlich halte es so, dass Antworten zu unerwünschten Fragen überhaupt keine Stimme – weder hoch noch runter – bekommen. Wenn man eine Stimme vergibt, sollte sich die rein an der Qualität der Antwort orientieren.

Gleiches gilt natürlich für die Qualität der Frage. Neben dem Schließungsvotum darf man gerne auch einen Abwärtsdaumen zeigen. Negativ bewertete Fragen verschwinden relativ schnell aus dem Blickfeld unangemeldeter Benutzer und werden von den Aufräumbots schneller gelöscht.

---

Obiges ist meine Meinung; selbstverständlich darf mir widersprochen werden.

Comment: Guter Punkt, das habe ich nicht bedacht

Comment: Ich habe dieser Antwort +1  gegeben. Mit dem Downvote wäre ich Neulingen gegenüber nicht ganz so hart. Ein freundlicher Kommentar und das Schließen der Frage erhöhen die Chance, dass aus einem unbedarften Neuling später mal eine Säule des Forums wird.

Answer (score 8):

Eine existierende Antwort negativ zu bewerten, nur weil sie eine off-topic-Frage beantwortet, finde ich aus folgenden Gründen ungerecht:

- Die Fragen sind nur geschlossen, wenn die fünf Close-Votes kriegen. Danach kann keine Antwort geschrieben werden. In der Zwischenzeit können aber Nutzer—die beispielsweise nicht die *Close-Votes* sehen dürfen und die Frage eher für on-topic halten—antworten. Diese Nutzer sind nicht daran schuld, dass wir nicht schnell genug die Frage geschlossen haben.
- Die Chronologie der etwaigen Edits und Kommentaren ist nicht übersichtlich. Man kann nicht wissen, was der Mensch, der die Antwort geschrieben hat, wusste.

Wie Janka zu meinen schien, wäre die Regel, dass es keine Regel geben darf.

Antworten auf off-topic-Fragen sind normale Antworten, die wegen deren Inhalt zu bewerten sind.

Comment: Ich sehe den Punkt der Aussage. Was ist nun, wenn ein Kommentar unter der Frage explizit um mehr Eigeninitiative bittet? Den können nämlich alle potentiellen Beantworter sehen.

Comment: Das ist ein Grund, die Frage als off-topic zu verdächtigen. Dafür ist "weniger als fünf" nicht eindeutig genug, würde ich mal behaupten. Wenn ein Kommentar tieferes oder überhaupt Recherchieren fördert, würde ich auch die Frage nur in Ausnahmefällen beantworten.

Comment: Keine uneingeschränkte Zustimmung: 1. hi-rep user beantworten auch OT Fragen, diese sollten *gern* mal ein DV abbekommen (Fall zu Fall, eindeutig ist's selten) 2. Was OPA wusste oder nicht ist mMn egal. Entscheidend ist, was auf'm Platz der Frage oder Antwort an Bemühen gezeigt wird (Kombination hirep A bei low-effort Q – oder ganzklar OT: DV) // Dies unter anderem, weil viele hireps SE-weit OT beantworten, CVs kommen, und imo wissentlich eine Monopolstellung für Antworten konstruiert wird sowie incentive für weitere OT Qs vom Antworter in Kauf genommen werden. (Für alte Posts schwierig…)

Comment: @LangLangC, Gegenmeinung: Manche Fragen schätzt OPA als unwichtig ein. Der Aufwand müsste auch an dem Interesse desjenigen gemessen werden. Jedenfalls sollte das Interesse nicht gänzlich in Abrede gestellt werden bloß weil verschwindend gering. Es ist doch billig, wenn die Frage von welchen beantwortet wird, denen es am leichtesten fällt. Ich könnte jetzt also auf eine aussichtlose Suche gehen, zu finden was "CV" heißt, oder direkt wen fragen, der es wissen müsste: Contra-Vote? Ich mein, mir kanns auch egal sein, klar. Warum dich oder etwa OPs, die auch benachrichtigt werden, damit behelligen.

Comment: close votes, ah jetz ja

Answer (score 0):

Wir sollten uns die grunsätzliche Frage stellen, was wir hier eigentlich bezwecken: natürlich kann man Antworten auf bestimmte Fragen in Wörterbüchern finden. Die Antworten auf praktisch alle hier gestellten Fragen kann man in irgendwelchen Büchern finden, denn über deutsche Grammatik, Wortschatz, Syntax, Etymologie, etc. wurden und werden meterweise Büücher geschrieben und vermutlich haben die wenigsten hier originäre diesbezügliche Erkenntnisse vorzuweisen - mithin ihre Weisheiten auch aus irgendwelchen Büchern.

Man könnte also, wenn alles, was in irgendeinem Buch steht, auch durch Eigenstudium herausgefunden werden kann, das ganze Forum schließen und stattdessen eine statische Seite mit dem Inhalt:

> Was du wissen willst steht in irgendeinem Buch, finde es und arbeite es durch.

ersetzen. Vielleicht liegt es ja an mir, aber mir kommt das ein kleines bißchen weniger hilfreich vor als die bisher gelebte Praxis.

Vielleicht würde auch die Beantwortung der folgenden Frage helfen, das Problem zu lösen: wozu macht man sich eigentlich die Arbeit, hier ((mit "hier meine ich SE insgesamt, German.SE im Besonderen) was zu schreiben, wenn man sich gleichzeitig Gedanken darüber macht, wie das, was man schreibt, für eine größtmögliche Zahl von Adressaten unbrauchbar gemacht werden kann?

Damit meine ich: die häufig wiederkehrenden Fragen kommen ja nicht deshalb häufig wieder, weil sich die Frager der Aufgabe verschrieben haben, uns im Allgemeinen und @infinitezero im Besonderen den letzten Nerv zu ziehen, sondern, weil offenbar ein (bis dato nicht gestilltes) Informationsbedürfnis herrscht, das - sonst würden die Leute ja nicht hier fragen - offfenbar nirgendwo anders gestillt werden kann.

Man kann trotzdem der Meinung sein, hier haben geefälligst nur ausgebildete Germanisten Fragen zu stellen, die sich mindestens auf Postdoc-Niveau bewegen müssen und - vorzuweisende - eigenständige wissenschaftliche Forschungen zur Grundlage haben zu haben - alles andere kann man in einem Buch nachschlagen, suchs halt gefälligst!

Mir fällt da ein Ausspruch eines ehemaligen, von mir sehr verehrten.  Vorgesetzen ein: "Was willst Du haben? Siebzig Prozent von irgendwas oder hundert Prozent von nichts?"

Comment: Ich ignoriere mal den überspitzten Kram weil der in einer Diskussion nicht hilfreich (kann mEn auch rauseditiert werden).
1) Eine Frage als ersten Schritt auf StackExchange zu stellen ist immer der falsche Weg. Aus dem [Helpcenter](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Please look around to see if your question has been asked before.". "If your question could be answered by a dictionary, thesaurus, or another general reference, consult these. Explain why this did not help you when asking your question." Es wird also immer erwartet erstmal Eigeninitiative zu seigen und nicht, die

Comment: Frage einfach auf "uns" abzuschieben. [Diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74453/funeral-vs-burial) ist ein gutes Beispiel dafür, wie man den Unterschied zwischen 2 Wörtern fragt. 2) Sinn von SE ist es weiterhin nicht, ein Wörterbuch oder andere **general** references zu duplizieren. Adjektivdeklination ist ein Kernkonzept von Deutsch. Ich kann die Frage bestimmt 100.000 mal mit einem anderen Adjektiv stellen. Warum sollte [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74420/why-erholsamen-and-not-erholsames) da besonders sein? Selbst wenn wir sie nicht wegen

Comment: "kann nachgeschlagen werden" schließen, dann sollte sie definitiv als Duplikat geschlossen werden, denn der Archetyp der Frage geht nicht um, warum steht hier X und nicht Y, sondern eigentlich um "Was ist Adjektivdeklination" und wurde unter Garantie schon [gestellt](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61050/adjective-suffixes-in-dativ). Diese Frage wurde übrigens auch geschlossen. Und darunter ist unsere eigene "general reference" verlinkt: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi

Comment: Du kannst: erstens gerne ignorieren, was Dir nicht paßt. Du kannst auch gerne rauseditieren, was dir nicht paßt. Du hast schließlich die Frage formuliert und es ist Dein gutes Recht, darauf nur Antworten zu bekommen, die von Dir selbst solange editiert wurden, bis sie Deine Vorstellung entsprechen. Deine Zitate aus dem Help Center plus "Es wird also immer erwartet erstmal Eigeninitiative zu seigen [sic] und nicht, die Frage einfach auf 'uns# abzuschieben. "  unterstellen, daß ich mich gegen eigenständige Recherche ausgesprochen hätte (bzw. deren Sinnhaftigkeit in Abrede gestellt hätte)

Comment: Was ich keineswegs getan habe. Damit diese Behauptung greift, solltest Du vielleicht meine Antwort erstmal einer Editierung unterziehen.

Comment: Weiters ist der Begriff "general reference" undefiniert und genau darauf habe ich mit meiner Überspitzung abgezielt. Darunter kann man so ziemlich alles verstehen und dann kann man die Frage nach der Adjektivflexion auch zum Beispiel so beantworten: "mit genügend Recherche hättest du das: https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110217360.3.166/pdf oder andere einschlägige Schriften zur Morphologie (https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110212617/htm) gefunden, deshalb CLOSED"

Comment: Mir scheint nicht, als wärst du an einer sachlichen Diskussion interessiert, sondern willst vor allem deinen Ärger an meiner Ansicht und Interpretation der Guidelines ablassen. Ich halte das hier für [lesenswert](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strohmann-Argument). Wenn dein Primärziel ist, Leuten zu helfen und du auch solche Fragen gerne (ständig) beantworten magst, wäre vielleicht gezielt ein Forum, keine Q&A Seite ein besserer Ort? Zur Recherche: Wo hat denn der Nutzer, dessen Frage diese Diskussion hier entzündet hat deiner Meinung nach Eigeninitiative gezeigt?

Comment: "Mir scheint nicht," Da scheint Dir wohl falsch. In so einem Fall könnte ich Dir auch böse Mails schreiben oder dgl.. Stattdessen schreibe ich mir hier die Finger wund, damit Du dann behaupten kannst, das sei nur meinem bösen Willen geschuldet, weil Du offenbar mit meinem Schreibstil nicht zurechtkommst. Um Deine Frage "Wo hat denn der User..." zu beantworten: nirgends, aber es geht mir ja auch nicht um diesen einen Thread, sondern um einen allgemeinen Gesichtspunkt. Du hast schließlich auch einen allgemeinen Punkt, der über den Anlaßfall hinausgreift, angesprochen.

Comment: Nachsatz: Ich habe auch was Lesenswertes für Dich, aber da "Reductio ad Absurdum" in jeder "general reference" zur Rhetorik nachzuschlagen ist, sag ich Dir ausdrücklich NICHT, wo's steht.

Comment: "**auch** böse Mails", wo habe ich das denn getan? Wenn dir "general references" zu ungenau sind, wäre dies doch ein guter Anlass einen neuen Post auf Meta zu schreiben indem wir klären, was genau unter dem Begriff verstanden wird und die entsprechende Sektion in der Hilfe updaten. Desweiteren scheint mir hier aber noch ein Missverständnis vorzuliegen, dass eine Frage zu schließen etwas negatives sei. Wenn ein Verweis auf eine Konjugationstabelle ausreicht und die Frage damit beantwortet ist, reicht das doch. Wenn das nicht so ist, hat der Nutzer die Möglichkeit, seine Frage zu editieren

Comment: und seine Frage zu spezifieren und die Frage wird wieder geöffnet. Genau so wie es doch sein sollte. Wenn der Konsens nun sein soll, das wir solche Fragen ohne weiteres zulassen wollen, dann sei es so, aber so wie es zur Zeit ist, ist es eindeutig off-topic und damit senkt es für mich die Qualität des SE.

Comment: OK, eins nach dem anderen: 1) mit "auch" habe ich "genausogut auch", bzw. "anstelle dessn, was ich jetzt tue" gemeint. Nirgendwo habe ich unterstellt, daß Du das tust und dies auch nicht beabsichtigt. 2) Ich habe weder angedeutet noch gesagt, daß ich das Schließen einer Frage für etwas Negatives halte. Ich behaupte lediglich (und das ist auch ohne weiteres einsichtig), daß mit dem schließen einer Frage zumindest dem Fragesteller nicht geholfen ist. Das kann man so akzeptieren, aber dann sollte man sich bewußt sein, daß man implizit damit sagt, nicht jedem in gleicher Weise helfen zu wollen.

Comment: Du kannst jetzt gerne einwenden, daß das ein Strohman-Argument sei, für mich ist es einfache Schlußfolgerung: wenn A, dann auch B. 3) Auch der Begriff "Qualität", den Du nun schon mehrfach gebrauchst, ist nicht definiert. Grundsätzlich läßt sich mit undefinierten Begriffen so ziemlich alles und das Gegenteil "beweisen". "So, wie es zurzeit ist, ist es ziemlich *krxl* und ich würde mir wünschen, daß es mehr *zwrd* ist." Das ergibt auch erst dann Sinn, wenn wir festlegen (und in dieser Festlegung übereinstimmen!), was wir unter "krxl" und "zwrd" verstehen. Ansonsten ist

Comment: das nur Kampfrhetorik a la "mehr schöneres Wetter für alle!".

Comment: Zunächst denke ich sollten wir einen neuen Thread auf Meta erstellen der genau klärt, was "general references" sind. Ich lasse Dir da gerne den Vorrang, aber kann das auch selbst tun. Am Ende profitiert der Fragensteller nämlich am meisten, wenn er weiß, wie er sich leicht selber helfen kann (z.B. das Wort online nachschlagen und alle deklinierten Formen sehen).

Answer (score -2):

Es gibt hier zwei verschiedene Ebenen:

1. Eine Frage ist sachlich "off topic".
2. Eine Frage ist als "off topic" markiert (entweder durch 5 Stimmen oder eine Mod-Stimme)

`1.` ist ein inhaltliches Kriterium. Daher kann hier Uneinigkeit herrschen. `2.` ist ein rein formales Kriterium, und daher klar.

Theoretisch kann jede Frage als off-topic bewertet werden. Daher sind hier zwei Schäden gegeneinander abzuwägen:

A) Mit dem Ansatz *Erst posten wenn eine Entscheidung getroffen ist* -- Hier werden potentiell hilfreiche Antworten auf Fragen nicht gepostet, weil Leute davor zurückschrecken, eine Antwort zu posten.

B) Mit dem Ansatz *Posten, solange es möglich ist* -- Hier werden Antworten zu Fragen gepostet, die sachlich off-topic sind (aber erst später diesen Status auch formal erhalten), und der Lerneffekt bei allen User:innen darüber, was hier als off-topic gilt, wird verwässtert.

In meinen Augen ist A) der größere Schaden.

Leute auf die Regeln zu konditionieren ist kein Wert an sich. Außerdem denke ich, dass die Maßnahme, Antworten zurückzuhalten, der falsche Ansatz ist, um den Schaden bei B) zu minimieren. Die Vagheit der Regel führt in meinen Augen eher zu Streit und Missgunst. Ein Teil dessen klingt schon in einem Kommentar zur Frage an:

> Vor allem bei einigen hochdotierten Usern, die die hiesigen Regeln gut kennen sollten, frage ich mich mittlerweile, ob die Regeln bewusst ignoriert werden, weil das eigene Punktekonto wichtiger ist.

Diese Spekulationen und diese Form von Streit unter den User:innen, die mit ihren Antworten die Säulen des Forums bilden, bringt uns nicht weiter, denke ich.

Aber viel grundsätzlicher halte ich das für den falschen Ansatz, weil es ein indirektes Mittel ist. Wir haben aber viel direktere Mittel, das Problem anzugehen, die wir zuerst ausschöpfen sollten: Wenn wir der Meinung sind, dass es zu lange dauert, dass Fragen geschlossen werden, dann sollten wir daran arbeiten -- User:innen, die darüber besorgt sind, könnten zum Beispiel Fragen häuiger als *in need of moderator intervention* flaggen, oder im Chat auf fragliche Threads aufmerksam machen, um die Entscheidung zu beschleunigen.

Daher sollte eine nicht geschlossen Frage in meinen Augen als formell on topic betrachtet werden.

Answer (score -4):

Du hast da links Knöpfe. Hoch/Runter. Nutze sie, tu dir keinen Zwang an. Völlig anonym. Du machst mit diesen Knöpfen deine eigenen Regeln.

Jeder andere aber auch.

Comment: Ich hab nicht auf DV gedrückt. Ich denke nicht, dass es hier um eigene Regeln machen geht. Wir sind eine Community und sollten daher einen kollektiven Leitfaden haben. Wenn wir sagen, auch wenn die Frage offtopic ist, voten wir gute Antworten hoch, revisite ich gerne die letzten 10 Fragen und hole das noch. Wenn wir sagen, wir voten das down, ebenso. Nur brauchen wir dazu erstmal eine Diskussion

Comment: Ich brauche kein Kollektiv. Ich habe einen eigenen Verstand und ich werde den auch benutzen. Und solange es diese wunderbar demokratischen Knöpfe gibt, werde ich die genau so bedienen, wie ich es für richtig halte. (Alle, die ein Kollektiv für ihre Meinungsfindung benötigen, sind natürlich völlig frei darin, sich statt an ihre eigenen Regeln an die Regeln zu halten, die irgendjemand anderes mal für sie aufgestellt hat.)

Comment: Es gibt doch auf kollektive Regeln was on-/offtopic ist. Oder entscheidest du das auch selbst?

Comment: Du hast es erfasst. Auch da gibt es Knöpfe. Und ob ich die nun drücke oder nicht, entscheide ich komplett selbst.

Comment: Hm, ich sehe nicht, dass die Diskussion dann noch zu irgendwas führt

Comment: Ich hatte dir ja schon anfangs geschrieben, dass es für dein schlechtes Gewissen gar keinen Grund gibt. Weder beim Beantworten von Fragen, die andere für schlecht halten, noch beim Herunter- oder Heraufwerten von Antworten auf diese Fragen.

Comment: Ich finde, die offtopic-Regeln sind nicht ganz gut bedacht, was daran liegt, dass man aus der Muttersprachlerperspektive nicht immer die Bedürfnisse der Lernenden richtig erkennen kann. Dann gibt es auch die Frage, was bei uns Vorrang hat und Hauptthema ist, Deutsch als Fremdsprache oder muttersprachlerische Fragen zu Schwierigfällen?

Comment: Die Frage korrekt zu formulieren ist meist schon ein Großteil der Lösung. Deshalb halte ich es auch für falsch, bei jeder Gelegenheit den Fragenden vor den Kopf zu schlagen. Aber wie ich schon sagte, das soll jeder für sich selbst entscheiden.